# Sparx EA version control how to merge two configurations?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have two configurations:

- ea-sparx
- CVS - Architecture

Both point to the same working copy path.  It seems that I have checked out an existing repository under one configuration (CVS - Architecture), but I have made changes and checked them in under the other configuration (ea-sparx).

**Question:** How can I move all my changes to the other configuration?

[image: Sparx Version Control]

Answer (score 2):

In the first place, Not sure how you changed the configuration of a controlled package. But if both are pointing to same working copy, Get All Latest should get you the latest. If you still have problems checking in / checking out, that could be due to due to out of synch, You can try "Resynch status with VC provider" for that package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what models you have created, but UML models are saved as XML-files. Those XML-files contains tags looking like

```
<UML:TaggedValue tag="packageFlags" value="Recurse=0;VCCFG=CVS - Architecture;"/>
```

or

```
<UML:TaggedValue tag="packageFlags" value="Recurse=0;VCCFG=ea-sparx;"/>
```

A possible solution:

- edit the XML-files manually: change ea-sparx to CVS - Architecture in your XML files
- remove the ea-sparx configuration from Enterprise Architect
- Get All Latest

Comment: Thanks - in the end, I exported the packages in the wrong configuration deleted them and re-imported.